# How can i sort a function?

Tags: python, function, random, dice

What i want to do with this code is roll 'n' number of dice and then find the lower quartile of it.

so far i have:

```
from random import randint
#Rolling the Die

numofdie = int(input("Please input the number of dice u want to roll: "))

if numofdie < 1:
  print ("PLease enter 1 or more")
  quit()
if numofdie > 100:
  print ("PLease enter a number less than 100")
  quit()

#Sum

def dicerolls():
    return [randint(1,6) for _ in range(numofdie)]
print (dicerolls())
```

Then i used the string.sort() function to try and sort the dicerolls() but realised that it will not work  as it is a function. How can i fix this and consequently be able to find the lower quartile.

Thanks

Comment: not quite sure what you mean by sort the dicerolls(). Do you mean sort the content of the list that is being returned in the function dicerolls()?

Comment: You could use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: Assign the function's return value to a variable then *sort the variable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the result in a variable, then sort that.

```
rolls = dicerolls()
rolls.sort()
print(rolls)
```

Or use the `sorted()` function:

```
print(sorted(dicerolls())
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `sorted()` function will return a sorted version of whatever list you give it. Since `dicerolls()` returns a list, you can add that list right in:

```
print(sorted(dicerolls()))
```